# Can I use time-fixed effects regression when there is already an independent variable in the model that is time-variant variable

Tags: regression, least-squares, panel-data, fixed-effects-model

For my research, I am using the following model, which tries to determine whether economic uncertainty (as measured by some proxies) influences fund inflows and outflows:

**Net fund flows** (i.e. money inflows or outflows) = β1 + **β2*economicuncertainty** + β3*laggedfundreturn + β4*fundage + β5*fundsize + β6*fundrisk + error term

All of the variables are time-variant.

My question is: can I use time-fixed effects? The reason for my doubt is that I already have economic uncertainty as an independent variable in the model, which is already a factor that affects ALL funds, and changes for every time period. What I would think is that when using a time-fixed effects model, this will mess up the slope coefficient of the economic uncertainty variable.

Thanks in advance, Jaap

---

Comment: If the time range is short (i.e. 1, 6, 12), a time-fixed effect is possible, but not recommended as your intuition suggests. There may be an explosion of collinearity/endogeneity between the variables. Are you trying to include TFE to "improve" overall significance?

Comment: Thank for the comment. To clarify, my time range is monthly from Dec. 2017 up to and including Feb. 2022 (i.e., 50 months). I am indeed trying to improve the overall significance and mitigate the omitted variable bias. Since I also have 50 different levels of economic uncertainty, all the same for every fund (as my research is limited to US data only), I am afraid that the time-fixed effects 'eat up' the relation of fund flows with economic uncertainty. When I add monthly fixed effects, this is indeed the case, changing the coefficient for economic uncertainty from a negative sign to positive

Comment: is this then indeed as you already explained caused by collinearity between the time fixed effects and the economic uncertainty variable?